# PayPal Rest API Create Express Checkout Payments returns empty string

Tags: php, curl, paypal, sandbox

I create a sandbox account with PayPal. And I can retrieve the access token via rest api using curl on PHP, however [Initiate a Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/create-express-checkout-payments/) just return empty string.

Anyone see a problem with the code? I can get result execute cURL request on centos server.

```
root@top [~]# curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
>    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>    -H "Authorization: Bearer A101.ZgOL9kEEHQVyKLqiQp4WeA2oOe-8afSL1LPrjdWAvJtqNyCUMHSAbnAnT46W-r48.XoUlfJnACl5jMpOtp2qsEJ0OHmy" \
>    -d '{"intent":"sale","redirect_urls":{"return_url":"http:\/\/www.baidu.com","cancel_url":"http:\/\/www.baidu.com"},"payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"4.00","currency":"USD","details":{"subtotal":"2.00","shipping":"1.00","tax":"2.00","shipping_discount":"-1.00"}},"item_list":{"items":[{"quantity":"1","name":"item 1","price":"1","currency":"USD","description":"item 1 description","tax":"1"},{"quantity":"1","name":"item 2","price":"1","currency":"USD","description":"item 2 description","tax":"1"}]},"description":"The payment transaction description.","invoice_number":"test111"}]}'


* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.82.78... connected
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com,OU=PayPal Production,O="PayPal, Inc.",L=San Jose,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Jan 13 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*       expire date: Jan 13 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*       common name: api.sandbox.paypal.com
*       issuer: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US
> POST /v1/payments/payment HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer A101.ZgOL9kEEHQVyKLqiQp4WeA2oOe-8afSL1LPrjdWAvJtqNyCUMHSAbnAnT46W-r48.XoUlfJnACl5jMpOtp2qsEJ0OHmy
> Content-Length: 616
> 
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Sun, 13 Nov 2016 13:12:44 GMT
< Server: Apache
< PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId=250
< Paypal-Debug-Id: aca89f52704ee
< CORRELATION-ID: aca89f52704ee
< Content-Language: *
< Paypal-Debug-Id: aca89f52704ee
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D3429247064%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3D; Expires=Sun, 13 Nov 2016 13:42:44 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< Vary: Authorization
< Content-Length: 1051
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
{"id":"PAY-0MY17200FH7226447LAUGNTA","intent":"sale","state":"created","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"4.00","currency":"USD","details":{"subtotal":"2.00","tax":"2.00","shipping":"1.00","shipping_discount":"-1.00"}},"description":"The payment transaction description.","invoice_number":"test111","item_list":{"items":[{"name":"item 1","description":"item 1 description","price":"1.00","currency":"USD","tax":"1.00","quantity":1},{"name":"item 2","description":"item 2 description","price":"1.00","currency":"USD","tax":"1.00","quantity":1}]},"related_resources":[]}],"create_time":"2016-11-13T13:12:44Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-0MY17200FH7226447LAUGNTA","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8MU45140N62388516","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-0MY17200FH7226447LAUGNTA/execute","rel":"* Closing connection #0
execute","method":"POST"}]}
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
class RestPayPalApi
{
    private $PP_SERVER;
    private $API_USER;

    public function __construct($account, $client_id, $secret, $is_sandbox=false)
    {
        $this->API_USER['ACCOUNT']   = $account;
        $this->API_USER['CLIENT_ID'] = $client_id;
        $this->API_USER['SECRET']    = $secret;
        if(!$is_sandbox) {
            $this->PP_SERVER['PP_CHECKOUT_HOST'] = 'https://api.paypal.com';
        } else {                                                   // use sandbox
            $this->PP_SERVER['PP_CHECKOUT_HOST'] = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com';
        }
    }

    public function create_payment()
    {
        $return_url = 'http://www.google.com';
        $cancel_url = 'http://www.google.com'; 
        $endpoint = '/v1/payments/payment';
        $url = $this -> PP_SERVER['PP_CHECKOUT_HOST'] . $endpoint;
        $invoice_number = 'test111';
        $access_token = $this -> get_access_token();
        $params = array(
                    'intent' => 'sale',
                    'redirect_urls' => array(
                                        'return_url' => $return_url,
                                        'cancel_url' => $cancel_url
                                    ),
                    'payer'  => array(
                                'payment_method' => 'paypal'
                            ),
                    "transactions" => array(
                        0 => array(
                            "amount" => array(
                                "total" => "4.00",
                                "currency" => "USD",
                                "details" => array(
                                    "subtotal" => "2.00",
                                    "shipping" => "1.00",
                                    "tax" => "2.00",
                                    "shipping_discount" => "-1.00"
                                )
                            ),
                            "item_list" => array(
                                "items" => array(
                                    array(
                                        "quantity" => "1",
                                        "name" => "item 1",
                                        "price" => "1",
                                        "currency" => "USD",
                                        "description" => "item 1 description",
                                        "tax" => "1"
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        "quantity" => "1",
                                        "name" => "item 2",
                                        "price" => "1",
                                        "currency" => "USD",
                                        "description" => "item 2 description",
                                        "tax" => "1"
                                    ),
                                )
                            ),
                            "description" => "The payment transaction description.",
                            "invoice_number" => "test111"
                        ),
                    ),
                );
        $data = json_encode($params);
        $header = array(
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                        'Content-Length' => strlen($data),
                        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
                        'Accept' => 'application/json',
                        'Accept-Language' => 'en_US'
                    );
        $addition_data = array(
                            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
                        );
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $url;
        print_r($header);
        print_r($params);
        echo $data;
        echo "</pre>";
        $result = $this -> execCurl($url, $data, $header, $addition_data);
        var_dump($result);exit;
        return $result;
    }

    protected function get_access_token()
    { 
        $endpoint = '/v1/oauth2/token';
        $url = $this -> PP_SERVER['PP_CHECKOUT_HOST'] . $endpoint;
        $data = array(
                    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
                );
        $header = array(
                        'Accept' => 'application/json',
                        'Accept-Language' => 'en_US'
                    );
        $addition_data = array(
                            CURLOPT_USERPWD => $this->API_USER['CLIENT_ID'] . ':' . $this->API_USER['SECRET'],
                            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
                        );
        $result = $this -> execCurl($url, $data, $header, $addition_data);

        $data = json_decode($result, true);
        if($data) {
            $access_token = $data['access_token'];
            $nonce = $data['nonce'];
            $token_type = $data['token_type'];
            $app_id = $data['app_id'];
            $expires_in = $data['expires_in'];
        } else {
            // something wrong ...
            return false;
        }

        return $access_token;
    }

    protected function execCurl($url, $data, $header=array(), $addition_data=array()) {
        if(is_array($data)) {
            $data = http_build_query($data, '', "&");
        }
        $defaults = array(
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'
        );
        if($addition_data) {
            $defaults = $addition_data + $defaults;
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $defaults);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (!$result) {
            var_dump($defaults);
            var_dump($result);
            exit('error: ' . curl_error($ch) . 'cURL failed');
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I create payment using below code:

```
$RestAPI = new RestPayPalApi(SANDBOX_PAYPAL_ACCOUNT, SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID, SANDBOX_SECRET, true);
$RestAPI -> create_payment();
```

here is doc ([Create Express Checkout payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/create-express-checkout-payments/)), I read again and again, but I really can't find something wrong.
Hope you can help me. Thx...

Comment: I have the same problem. hope anyone can reslove this problem.